# Second DisplayAlert hanging

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, async-await, xamarin.uwp

I am using Xamarin Forms to build an app and I am having issues with a `DisplayAlert` firing once, but hanging the second time.

Please consider the following code:

```
ThisThingClickedCommand = new Command(
async () =>
{
    var continue = true;
    if (SomeVariable.is_flagged == 0)
    {
        continue = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("User Question", "This is a question for the user", "Yes", "No");
    }

    if (continue)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This debug fires");
        var AnswerToSecondQuestion = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("Second Question", "This is a second question for the user", "Yes", "No");
        if (AnswerToSecondQuestion)
        {
            // Do more things
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("This one does not :(");
    }
}),
```

The code above has been in a project for a long time and has always seemed to work, until a recent update to Visual Studio 2017 and subsequently some new target versions of Windows.

When I launch the app on Windows (untested on other devices currently) and this particular bit of code runs, the first `DisplayAlert` shows with no issues, however the second `DisplayAlert` never shows and the app hangs waiting for it's answer (I assume).

If anyone can explain how to *solve* this, i'd be grateful, but if they can explain *why* this happens as well, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread to ensure the UI thread handles the second call:

```
     ThisThingClickedCommand = new Command(
    async ()=>
    {
        var continue = true;
        if (SomeVariable.is_flagged == 0)
        {
            continue = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("User Question", "This is a question for the user", "Yes", "No");
        }

        if (continue)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This debug fires");

Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            var AnswerToSecondQuestion = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("Second Question", "This is a second question for the user", "Yes", "No");
            if (AnswerToSecondQuestion)
            {
                // Do more things
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("This one does not :(");
        });
    }),
```

Indeed, after an await, you need to be sure that the execution continues on the UI thread if you want to manipulate Methods or Properties manipulating the UI

Comment: After some code-movement this solution works. If you wouldn't mind updating the answer to explain WHY this works for people in the future. I shall accept this answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `async void` fire and forget methods, which is what that command action delegate will be converted to. The one exception being for event handlers.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Create an event and handler

```
private event EventHandler raiseAlerts = delegate { };
private async void OnRaiseAlerts(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var _continue = true;
    if (SomeVariable.is_flagged == 0) {
        _continue = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("User Question", "This is a question for the user", "Yes", "No");
    }

    if (_continue) {
        Debug.WriteLine("This debug fires");
        var AnswerToSecondQuestion = await PageSent.DisplayAlert("Second Question", "This is a second question for the user", "Yes", "No");
        if (AnswerToSecondQuestion) {
            // Do more things
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("This one does not :(");
    }
}
```

Subscribe to the event. Most probably in the constructor

```
raiseAlerts += OnRaiseAlerts
```

And raise the event in the command action delegate

```
ThisThingClickedCommand = new Command(() => raiseAlerts(this, EventArgs.Empty));
```

Should at least now be able to catch any thrown exceptions to understand what problems if any, exists.

Comment: Rudy's solution appears to have solved the issue, so have accepted his answer. I will use the info you provided to make my code "best practise" as well. Thank you for your efforts.